# Unity Android cant build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

Unity 2019.3.15f1
Using the Android SDK, NDK and JDK installed by Unity hub

I get the following error when I try to build

```
  C:\PROJECTS\NEWS2\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\processReleaseManifest\bundle-manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:58: error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

There are actually 66 errors that show up when the build fails, but I think probably the one above is the salient one.

[image]

UPDATE:
I tried reimport all, No change.

My colleague is able to build on his mac. I have Windows 10. I have also built this project before to Android no problem. So something in my environment is the issue I guess. I did install Android Studio relatively recently, that may have mucked up my system.. I also found a system variable for Android SDK in environment variables, I deleted it, restarted, but still get the same error.

UPDATE 2
So I am able to build another project using the same version of Unity ok.. So it is not purely my environment that is at fault...

Answer (score 1):

check your SDk and NDK and Java are knowen by Unity;
must be like those

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihijb.png)

..
which target Api you chose ?? API 29(if you want to publish it to google play atleast Target Api 29)

Comment: Yeah its exactly like that

Comment: Its set to "automatic (highest installed)" .. all the settings are just default, I havent changed anhthing